Sending HTML form through Flask to SQL database is causing an extra row that has all NULL values?
I just need some help understanding what I did wrong haha. I would love it if someone could explain why it happened as well as offer a solution. This would help me greatly understanding what to look out for in the future.
So I have an HTML form that sends data to my app.py and that's working fine. What happened though is when I hit the submit button on the website, it will produce two rows. One is completely NULL values and one is the correct information.
I followed some documentation to get where I am now, so I am a bit confused as to why this happened.
Here is the app.py code:
@app.route ('/feedback', methods = ["GET","POST"])
def feedback():
        username = request.form.get("username")
        public = request.form.get("public")
        contact = request.form.get("contact")
        feedback_desc = request.form.get("feedback_desc")
        email = request.form.get("email")
        timestamp = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        conn = db_connect()
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(
            "INSERT INTO users (id, username, contact, email, feedback_desc, created_at, is_public) VALUES (DEFAULT,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (username,contact,email,feedback_desc,timestamp,public)
            )
        conn.commit()

        return render_template("feedback.html")

And here is the HTML form:
    <div class="content">
        <div class="feedback-content">
            <div>
                <h1>Let's Gather Some Info</h1>
                <br>
                <form action="{{ url_for('feedback')}}" method="post">
                    <label for="name">Your Discord Name</label><br>
                        <input type="text" class="name" name="username">
                    <br><br>

                    
                    <label for="is-public">Would you like to be your submission to be public or private?</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="public" id="yes_public" value="Public"> Yes </input><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="public" id="no_public" value="Not Public"> No </input><br>
                    <br><br>

                        <label for="email">Write your email below</label>
                        <input type="text" class="email" name="email">
                    <br><br>

                    <label for="should-contact">Would you like to be contacted by our team regarding your submission?</label><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="contact" id="yes_contact" value="Contact"> Yes </input><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="contact" id="no_contact" value="Don't Contact"> No </input><br>
                    <br><br>

                    <label for="form-text">Please write your thoughts below:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-text" name="feedback_desc"><br><br>
                            <button type="submit">Submit Your Feedback</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

And here is a screenshot of the result attached.
I was expecting the HTML form when submitted to talk with my app.py and send ONE row of data, with all the information from the HTML form, to the SQL database.
SOLVED! I needed to add an if statement for POST. Answer is in the comments.

could you kindly check if the timestamp values are same or different ? If they are different, possibly it is working correctly.

You don't differentiate between POST and GET. This means that with a GET request an empty row is added and with a POST request a row with the data contained in the form is added. Use if request.method == 'POST': to distinguish whether it is a POST request.

Thank you @Detlef that ficed it. s13rw81 thanks for your suggestion as well
